# Change of basis from falling powers to powers for polynomials up to degree $n$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Notice that
$$(1, x, x^{\underline{2}}, x^{\underline{3}}, \dots)$$
and
$$(1, x, x^2, x^3, \dots) $$
both are bases of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ (where $x^{\underline{n}}$ is the falling power). Now suppose the finite case where
$$(1, x, x^{\underline{2}}, x^{\underline{3}}, \dots, x^{\underline{n}})$$
and
$$(1, x, x^2, x^3, \dots, x^n) $$
span all real polynomials up to degree $n$. What is the base change matrix from the first basis to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements of the base change matrix from first basis to second are the Stirling numbers of the second kind, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number . (Consequently coordinates in first basis transform to coordinates in the second basis by multiplying with a matrix with elements that are Stirling numbers of first kind, which is the inverse of the base change matrix).